# breadcrumbs in spring

Tags: java, beginner, spring

Breadcrumbs should look like this:
Home > Mobiles & Tablets > Mobile Phones > Phone Super Duper

every product belongs only to one category. e.g Phone Super Duper can be found only under Mobile Phones.
This is just a sketch but i want to know your opinion if the direction is ok or i should change the strategy.

ANY critique or suggestions are welcome
 JSP

```
<div id="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
    <c:forEach items="${breadcrumbs}" var="breadcrumb" varStatus="status">
        <li class="separator">&gt;</li>
        <li><c:choose>
                <c:when test="${breadcrumb.url eq '#'}">
                    <a href="#" onclick="return false;"
                        <c:if test="${status.last}">class="last"</c:if>>${breadcrumb.name}</a>
                </c:when>

                <c:otherwise>
                    <a href="${baseURL2}${breadcrumb.url}"
                        <c:if test="${status.last}">class="last"</c:if>>${breadcrumb.name}</a>
                </c:otherwise>

            </c:choose></li>
    </c:forEach>
```

HomePageController

```
@RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHomePage(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("breadcrumbs", contentPageBreadcrumbBuilder.getBreadcrumbs(request.getServletPath()));
        return "welcome";
    }
```

ProductPageController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product")
    public String getProductById(@RequestParam("id") int productId, Model model) {
        Product product = new Product();
        Category  category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("someCategory");
        product.setProductId(1);
        product.setProductName("someProductName");
        product.setCategory(category);
        model.addAttribute("breadcrumbs",  productBreadcrumbBuilder.getBreadcrumbs(product));
        return "product";
    }
```

ProductBreadcrumbsBuilder

```
@Component
public class ProductBreadcrumbBuilder {
    public List<Breadcrumb> getBreadcrumbs(final Product productModel) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            final List<Breadcrumb> breadcrumbs = new ArrayList<>();
            breadcrumbs.add(getProductBreadcrumb(productModel));
            Breadcrumb category = getCategoryBreadcrumb(productModel.getCategory());
            breadcrumbs.add(category);
            Collections.reverse(breadcrumbs);
            return breadcrumbs;
        }

        protected Breadcrumb getProductBreadcrumb(final Product product) {
            final String productUrl = "/products/" + product.getProductId();
            return new Breadcrumb(productUrl, product.getProductName());
        }

        protected Breadcrumb getCategoryBreadcrumb(final Category category) {
            final String categoryUrl = "/categories/" + category.getId();
            return new Breadcrumb(categoryUrl, category.getCategoryName());
        }
```

Breadcrumb

```
public class Breadcrumb {

    private String url;
    private String name;

    public Breadcrumb(final String url, final String name)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

REST apis usually have

```
GET /products - retrieves all products  
GET /products/10 - retrieves product with id 10.
```

And thus I'd suggest that instead of requesting `GET /product?id=10`, you do `GET /product/10`.

Take a look at the URL in your webbrowser - this is `GET /questions/119636/`.